# what we should write in params.properties file for jpbc

Tags: java

I am not from mathematics background and the person who need this is having a bit knowledge of java.

We are using jpbc library.

We need Pairing object which i get from

```
import it.unisa.dia.gas.jpbc.*;
import it.unisa.dia.gas.plaf.jpbc.pairing.PairingFactory;

Pairing pairing = PairingFactory.getPairing("params.properties");
```

What should be written in params.properties? I mean what should be key and How its value will be defined.

We know that we have to define bilinear map in that file but how ?

I searched a lot but could not find.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The params.properties file is used to enter the parameters which can be used to draw the ellip[tic curve and further can be used to generate the elements and field based on the parameters input in the file.

Comment: can you give an example?